# Python class __init__ override, TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python for a few days and I'm trying to make a subclass to an existing class but I can't find the error. I tried everything but i think that I'm just blind...

Output always gives such an error

```
dog = Dog('Max', 120, 50, 'Woff', 'Tom')
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

And here is the code, Animal part with Garfield cat is working fine.

```
class Dog(Animal):
    __owner = ""

    def __init(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

dog = Dog('Max', 120, 50, 'Woff', 'Tom') #<==== HERE ERROR OCCURES
```

Comment: Post the source for `Dog` class

Comment: @GarbageCollector It's buried in there, near the bottom. OP, most of the methods posted aren't relevant to your issue, please consider cutting down your code to only the relevant parts. As to indentation, you only need to copy/paste your code block, highlight it all in one go and click the `{}` button in editor or use ctrl+k.

Comment: It makes no sense defining owner at the class level. And even less sense giving it a double underscore prefix.

Comment: BTW, `toSting` should be `__str__`. That way you can pass your class instances to `str()`, or print them. Also, we don't normally implement getters and setters for simple attributes in Python, we access the attributes directly. And if you do really need actual getter and setter methods, it's much nicer to implement them as properties, so callers can still access them as if they were simple attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The method **init** in Dog should be with the __ at the end too:

```
class Dog(Animal):
    __owner = ""

# here
def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
    self.__owner = owner
    super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)
```

Comment: Thanks! Who would win? Bunch of programmes or two underscores?

Comment: It also needs to be intended once to be inside the Dog class, not at global level.

Comment: Now this function gives an error:
`def toString(self): return '{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and say {} and his owner is {}'.format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound, self.__owner)`

prints out: 

`return '{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and say {} and his owner is {}'.format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound, self.__owner)
AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog__name'`

Comment: @MarcinMaicki `.format(self.name, self.height, self.weight, self.sound, self.owner)`

Answer (score 0):

Your init method of dog class has the wrong name, hence it doesn't override the base class init, which takes 5 arguments.

```
def __init(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
    self.__owner = owner
    super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)
```

You are missing `__` at the end of the function. It shouild be `def __init__(..)`